# Mudar menu com CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que gostaria que quando rolasse a barra da pagina ate a metade da pagina aparecesse um menu flutuante que ficasse fixado na parte de cima da pagina mas não sei como fazer.

Pagina normal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML da Pagina normal

```
  <div class="menu_superior">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8">

            <ul class="top">
                <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 8744-3399</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> teste#hotmail.com</li>    
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul class="redes_sociais">
                <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" action="" ></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" action=""></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-linkedin" action=""></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" action=""></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" action=""></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Menu que gostaria que aparecesse fixado na parte de cima da pagina quando rolasse a barra da pagina ate a metade da pagina

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML do menu que gostaria que aparecesse fixado na parte de cima da pagina quando rolasse a barra da pagina ate a metade da pagina.

```
<div class="header-fixed2">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3" >
         <img src="imagens/kalunga.JPG" style="width:180px;" class="imagem_empresa2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
         <div class="busca"><input type="text" id="campo_busca" placeholder="O que você procura?"><button type="submit" onclick="" class="buscar_produto2"><i class="fa fa-search" action="" ></i></button> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5"> 
         <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropbtn">
               <c:choose>
                  <c:when test="${empty param.nome}">
                  <img src="imagens/pessoa2.png" alt="usuario" class="imagem_usuario"> Entre/Cadastre-se<span class="caret"></span>
                  </c:when>    
                  <c:otherwise>
                     <p>${param.nome}</p> 
                  </c:otherwise>
               </c:choose>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Meus Pedidos</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Meus Dados</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Fale Conosco</a></li>
               <li><a href="Logout"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Sair</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"> Não é Cadastrado?Cadastre-se</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><button type="button" onclick="" class="btn_entrar" >Entrar</button> </a></li>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <div id="carrinho2">
               <a href="#"><img src="imagens/carrinho2.png" class="carrinho2">()itens</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-fixed2{
   background-color: white;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 999;
   width: 100%;
   display: none;
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   height: 74px;
   display: block;
}

.buscar_produto2{
   border: 0px solid;
   border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
   color:#C0C0C0;
   height: 33px;
   width: 40px;
   float: left;
   background-color:black;
   color:#ffffff;
}

.imagem_empresa2{
}

#carrinho2{
   margin-top: 20px;
}

#carrinho2 a{
   color:black !important;
   font-size: 12pt;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#carrinho2 a:hover{
   color:black !important;
   font-size: 12pt;
}
```

UPDATE
Acontece um erro ao carregar a pagina ele mostra os dois meus ao mesmo tempo, sendo que queria que quando carregar a pagina mostrasse o menu azul e quando eu rolar a barra de rolagem mostra-se o segundo menu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: no caso seria Janela

Comment: O segundo menu fica invisível ao carregar a página?

Comment: não ele fica visivel,no caso ele sobrepõe o primeiro menu da imagem que enviei

Comment: O segundo menu fica visível onde no carregamento da página?

Comment: na parte de cima da pagina, sobrepõe o  <div class="menu_superior"></div>

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha resposta. Não entendi direito. Os dois menus irão aparecer ao mesmo tempo ao abrir a página? E depois de rolar só o segundo que irá ficar visível?

Comment: Dvd fiz um UPDTADE na pergunta coloquei a imagem de como esta a pagina, queria  que quando carregar a pagina mostrasse o menu azul e quando eu rolar a barra de rolagem mostra-se o segundo menu, mas ele mostra os dois um em baixo do outro quando carrega a pagina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é um exemplo funcional que você deve aplicar ao seu código. O segundo menu com class `header-fixed2` deverá estar oculto com `display: none;`. Ao rolar a tela até a metade, o primeiro menu irá se ocultar e o segundo aparecer:

```js
$(window).on("scroll load",function(){
   var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop();
   var altJanela = window.innerHeight;
   if(scrlTopo >= altJanela/2){
      $(".header-fixed").hide();
      $(".header-fixed2").show();
   }else{
      $(".header-fixed").show();
      $(".header-fixed2").hide();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-fixed" style="display: block; float: left; width: 100%; height: 50px; background: red; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999;">
   menu 1
</div> 

<div class="header-fixed2" style="display: block; float: left; width: 100%; height: 50px; background: yellow; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999; display: none;">
   menu 2
</div> 
<br /><br /><br />
Role para baixo
<br /><br /><br />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam venenatis, tortor ut posuere tempus, massa massa maximus ex, eu tempus enim mauris ac dui. Mauris et fringilla dolor. Vivamus maximus quam elit, sed elementum ante luctus at. Curabitur nisl ipsum, viverra sed pellentesque in, ultrices vitae odio. Nullam iaculis, quam at imperdiet dignissim, ipsum nibh lacinia quam, a venenatis lectus nibh sit amet nisl. Suspendisse a interdum sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla nec enim elit. Donec mollis finibus nibh, ac vehicula tortor vehicula vel. Maecenas congue iaculis feugiat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam venenatis, tortor ut posuere tempus, massa massa maximus ex, eu tempus enim mauris ac dui. Mauris et fringilla dolor. Vivamus maximus quam elit, sed elementum ante luctus at. Curabitur nisl ipsum, viverra sed pellentesque in, ultrices vitae odio. Nullam iaculis, quam at imperdiet dignissim, ipsum nibh lacinia quam, a venenatis lectus nibh sit amet nisl. Suspendisse a interdum sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla nec enim elit. Donec mollis finibus nibh, ac vehicula tortor vehicula vel. Maecenas congue iaculis feugiat.</p>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam venenatis, tortor ut posuere tempus, massa massa maximus ex, eu tempus enim mauris ac dui. Mauris et fringilla dolor. Vivamus maximus quam elit, sed elementum ante luctus at. Curabitur nisl ipsum, viverra sed pellentesque in, ultrices vitae odio. Nullam iaculis, quam at imperdiet dignissim, ipsum nibh lacinia quam, a venenatis lectus nibh sit amet nisl. Suspendisse a interdum sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla nec enim elit. Donec mollis finibus nibh, ac vehicula tortor vehicula vel. Maecenas congue iaculis feugiat.</p>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam venenatis, tortor ut posuere tempus, massa massa maximus ex, eu tempus enim mauris ac dui. Mauris et fringilla dolor. Vivamus maximus quam elit, sed elementum ante luctus at. Curabitur nisl ipsum, viverra sed pellentesque in, ultrices vitae odio. Nullam iaculis, quam at imperdiet dignissim, ipsum nibh lacinia quam, a venenatis lectus nibh sit amet nisl. Suspendisse a interdum sem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla nec enim elit. Donec mollis finibus nibh, ac vehicula tortor vehicula vel. Maecenas congue iaculis feugiat.</p>
```

Comment: Faltou incluir o **jQuery** :)

Comment: Dvd fiz um UPDTADE na pergunta coloquei a imagem de como esta a pagina, queria que quando carregar a pagina mostrasse o menu azul e quando eu rolar a barra de rolagem mostra-se o segundo menu, mas ele mostra os dois um em baixo do outro quando carrega a pagina

Comment: @User1999 Fiz as modificações. É só deixar o segundo menu oculto, que irá aparecer ao rolar a tela.

Comment: funcionou DvD obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Da uma olhada nisso aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

Pode te ajudar e te dar um rumo do que pesquisar.